# Working with accents in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, utf-8

I have a list of city names. If the user picks one I'd like to set the center of my angular-google-map's to that certain city. 
console.log works fine I get back the correct city name but if I pass it to a function it's replacing the accents.

```
$scope.selectCity = function (city) {
  console.log(city.name) //it works fine. The log: Abaújkér
  locationService.getLatLngByCityName(city.name).then(function (result){
    var cityLatLng = result.data.results[0].geometry.location;

    console.log(cityLatLng);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

locationService.getLatLngByCityName returns with bad request:

> GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Aba%FAjk%E9r&sensor=true 400 (Bad Request)

The factory:

```
factory.getLatLngByCityName = function (city) {
  console.log(city); // it works fine. The log: Abaújkér
  var API_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + city;
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: API_URL,
    params: { sensor: true }
  })
    .catch(function () {
    return $q.reject();
  });
}
```

I guess its something with the encoding. How could I fix the googleapis' URL?

Comment: use encodeURI(uri); on city name

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vanojx1! It works. If you could post it as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to url encode GET parameters with "special chars", use this function:

[encodeURI()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)